# Getting NullPointerException when trying to get serialized object in Restlet

Tags: android, object, serialization, nullpointerexception, restlet

I am developing a restlet server inside a Glassfish server that will receive petitions from an Android client.

Based on the [Hello World application](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/firstSteps) and on the [Object serialization tutorial](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet/version/11)

Here's some code:

---

Server Side

MyUser.java

```
package com.server.common;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class MyUser implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String username;

public MyUser() {}

public MyUser(String username) {
    super();
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
}
```

UserResource.java

```
package com.server.common;

import org.restlet.resource.Get;

public interface UserResource {
@Get
public MyUser getUser();
}
```

UserServerResource.java

```
package com.server;

import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;
import com.server.common.MyUser;
import com.server.common.UserResource;

public class UserServerResource extends ServerResource implements UserResource {

@Get
public MyUser getUser() {
    MyUser u = new MyUser("Nickname from server");
    return u;
}
}
```

---

Client Side

- The same UserResource.java and MyUser.java inside the package `com.client.common`
- MainActivity.java extract

  ```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(
          "http://MYSERVERIP:8080/FamilyWeb/username");
  resource = cr.wrap(UserResource.class);

  try {
      MyUser u = resource.getUser();
      Log.w("success",u.toString());
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

---

LogCat

```
09-29 22:31:52.650: W/System.err(1409): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-29 22:31:52.650: W/System.err(1409):     at com.dimunoz.family.tablet.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
09-29 22:31:52.650: W/System.err(1409):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-29 22:31:52.650: W/System.err(1409):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-29 22:31:52.660: W/System.err(1409):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
09-29 22:31:52.660: W/System.err(1409):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-29 22:31:52.660: W/System.err(1409):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-29 22:31:52.660: W/System.err(1409):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-29 22:31:52.660: W/System.err(1409):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 22:31:52.660: W/System.err(1409):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-29 22:31:52.660: W/System.err(1409):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-29 22:31:52.660: W/System.err(1409):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 22:31:52.660: W/System.err(1409):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-29 22:31:52.660: W/System.err(1409):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-29 22:31:52.660: W/System.err(1409):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-29 22:31:52.660: W/System.err(1409):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I change the getUser() method to return a String object and make the respective changes, my Android client gets the response, but if I run the code shown above, I get a NullPointerException.

What am I missing?

Comment: You don't seem to be setting it before getting it and, since String is an Object, will return null unless it's been set, or initialised at declaration.  Anyway, the logcat output should confirm.  Please post it.

Comment: Actually, I am setting it. MyUser u = new MyUser("Nickname from server") calls the constructor MyUser(String username)

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry.  The logcat might still help though.  What line is causing the exception?

Comment: the Log.w("success",u.toString()); line. Watching the problem in debug mode, I saw that the MyUser object is null.

Comment: @Simon I just added the LogCat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the name of the common files packages was different in the server and the client, so the solution was to rename them to the same name.

In the [Restlet Mailing List](http://restlet.tigris.org/ds/viewForumSummary.do?dsForumId=4447) one of the moderators, Thierry Boileau, answered me why they should have the same name:

> the common classes between the server and client parts (such as the classes
>   for the bean objects that are serialized/deserialized) must be located in
>   the same packages. The reason is that the serialization/deserialization
>   process leverages conventions, in particular convention regarding the full
>   path of the bean classes are referenced inside the JSON representation.
>   All other classes such as ClientResource, annotated interfaces could be
>   located in distinct packages between client/server projects.